# How to find the critical value $c$ that the left-hand side of $c$ has probability 0.95 under the empirical distribution curve?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, python

Assuming there is a data set $X$ and the histogram shows below, how could I find the critical value $c$ that the left-hand side of $c$ has probability 0.95 under the empirical distribution curve? Is there any package in R or Python could calculate this $c$? Many thanks.

Based on this data, we could find an empirical distribution and the area under this distribution function is 1. The area on the left-hand side of $c$ is 0.95. It is just like the critical value in one tail hypothesis test. 
[image]

Comment: Would it be fair to interpret your question as asking how to find the smallest value that equals or exceeds 95% of your data?  If not, could you explain what you mean by "critical value"?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your advice, let me think how to state properly.

Comment: It still reads like you are asking for the 95th percentile.  See `?quantile` in `R`, for instance.

Comment: @whuber Yes, you are right, they are equivalent, sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there:

I think I understand your question as I usually need to draw conclusion from my hypothesis testing using empirical (or boostrapped) distribution.

If I understand correctly, the solution of your question is simple. Let $\hat{f}(x)$ be the estimated density (i.e., the value you plot on the y-axis). To locate the critical value $c_{0.95}$ you are looking for, suppose your random variable $X$ gives your 100 observation $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$. Then you need to sort $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and its corresponding estimated density $\hat{f}(x_i)$ from the lowest to the highest (i.e., an ascending order).

Now $c_{0.95}$ is actually the 95th element of the sorted $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$, and you can find its corresponding estimated density $\hat{f}(c_{0.95})$.

Hope this help.

Comment: I didn't notice that you are using R. you can use the command: sort(x)[round(quantile(c(1:100), 0.95))], where 100 refers to your sample size, and 0.95 is your critical value.

Comment: @Rico What seems to be needed here is the inverse of the ecdf, so `quantile(x,0.95,type=1)` would be the obvious R code for that.

Comment: Sorting is unnecessary. `quantile(x, 0.95)` will do it. This is worth knowing, because individual quantiles can be found in $O(n)$ time while sorting requires $O(n\log(n))$ time.

Comment: @whuber I agree .. but I think we would choose a different definition of "quantile" to the default. (as per my comment above)

Comment: @Glen_b That's fine--the distinctions among the different conventions to compute quantiles seem to be a tangential issue.  The main point is to observe that there are better ways than sorting and that neither sorting nor anything computationally equivalent to it is needed.